# how to run SwiftLint on uncommitted files for m1

Tags: xcode, swiftlint

I found this shell script

```
# Run SwiftLint
START_DATE=$(date +"%s")

SWIFT_LINT=/usr/local/bin/swiftlint

# Run SwiftLint for given filename
run_swiftlint() {
    local filename="${1}"
    if [[ "${filename##*.}" == "swift" ]]; then
        #${SWIFT_LINT} autocorrect --path "${filename}"
        ${SWIFT_LINT} lint --path "${filename}"
    fi
}

if [[ -e "${SWIFT_LINT}" ]]; then
    echo "SwiftLint version: $(${SWIFT_LINT} version)"
    # Run for both staged and unstaged files
    git diff --name-only | while read filename; do run_swiftlint "${filename}"; done
    git diff --cached --name-only | while read filename; do run_swiftlint "${filename}"; done
else
    echo "${SWIFT_LINT} is not installed."
    exit 0
fi

END_DATE=$(date +"%s")

DIFF=$(($END_DATE - $START_DATE))
echo "SwiftLint took $(($DIFF / 60)) minutes and $(($DIFF % 60)) seconds to complete."
```

Over here
https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/413#issuecomment-184077062

Which worked pretty well till I updated my computer to the new M1 chip.

According to this blog
https://www.anotheriosdevblog.com/installing-swiftlint-on-a-m1/
We should change the location of the path.
I suspect it has something to do with the location SwiftLint is installed:

However I'm not to familiar with home-brew or shell script to get it working.

Comment: Is there any reason why not to run lint on the whole project?

Comment: Too many warnings, errors to deal with at once. Also don't have the time as features/bug fixes are higher priority than fixing lint warnings. Once we get to a point where most warnings are fixed we can run lint on the whole project.

Comment: can you run swiftlint manually? In general there is no need to put the whole path of swiftlint. It should be enough to use `SWIFT_LINT=swiftlint`

Comment: SwiftLint runs manually so if I say swiftlint in the terminal then it works. not sure why we have to give the path where its installed but saying SWIFT_LINT=swiftlint breaks it while saying SWIFT_LINT=/opt/homebrew/bin/swiftlint makes it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Home-brew location has changed on the new Macs.

changing

```
SWIFT_LINT=/usr/local/bin/swiftlint
```

to

```
SWIFT_LINT=/opt/homebrew/bin/swiftlint
```

Fixed the issue